# Get colour space of an image in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, gm

I need to loop through a list of JPEG images to see if their colorspace is RGB. How do I do a check? I see the [GM](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html) documents and it states the way to set the colourspace not get. How do I get the colourspace of an image?